# Weird artifacts when using Tmax 100 for black-and-white reversal processing

Tags: film, developing, darkroom

I'm new to film development and previously managed to develop two rolls of Kodak Tri-x 400 (let's call roll A and B) using reversal processing: D-11, dichromate bleach, D-72. Today I tried to develop another roll of Kodak Tmax 100 (roll C). But the result was not good:

1. roll C is very dark (my camera was set to DX ISO 100 when taking the pictures) though most of the photos were properly exposed, and I even used last 10 photos to test different compensation: 0, +0.1, +1, all are about the same darkness. Therefore, the contrast is way lower than roll A and B.
2. what's worse, I noticed some artifacts (see the photo below, you can notice the abnormal color around all dark parts) in the dark region of many photos. Suspect it was so dark so something got wrong during the reversal process.
3. The phenomenon in 2 also happened to some photos of roll A, but not roll B.
4. I believe most of the photos are properly exposed (I could get some decent photos if I had used negative film development, I guess).

Here are two sample photos from roll A:

Most photos are good:
[image: Most photos are good]

But are sporadically with artifacts in dark zone:
[image: With weird artifacts]

Here is a sample photo from roll B (looking good):
All photos are good, including portraits in similar light conditions:
[image: The dark part looks natural]

Here are the samples from roll C (too dark, artifacts around dark region):

Was properly exposed, taken on a day with good light condition:
[image: Was properly exposed, taken on a day with good light condition]
Bad portrait because of the artifacts (look at the hair), also noticed the artifacts are in the previous photo:
[image: Bad portrait because of the artifacts]
Too dark, also suffer from the artifact problem:
[image: Too dark, also suffer from the artifact problem]

TL;DR: I tried reversal processing using D-11, dichromate bleach and D-72, but (1) got very dark photos when switched from ISO 400 to 100 (both were properly exposed), and (2) also got annoying artifacts in dark zone when it becomes really dark. But for the same formula, roll B is well developed. roll A is the same type of roll as roll B, but with different ISO from roll C.

EDIT: I recalled that I did notice greenish color in the problematic area during the second exposure (after bleaching and clearing). Does that mean the clearing is not enough and some parts were still contaminated by dichromate?

Comment: Did you use the same development times for the Kodak Tmax 100? That is unlikely to work as expected.

Comment: @jarnbjo Yes, I did. But what about the artifacts..?

Comment: The artifacts look like very normal solarization, which in a reversal process can be caused both by overexposure, underexposure or many errors in either of the two development steps (duration, temperature or developer concentration).

Comment: @jarnbjo I did opened the tank during the second development, but then closed the lid again. I thought it would be ok because before the second dev, the film should be fully exposed. With the exposed positive image, all the silver halide should be consumed so it won't really change anything if you even operate the second development with light, right?

Comment: After completing the bleach bath, you can do all further steps of the reversal process in full brightness. Opening the tank during second development will have no influence on the result.

Comment: Are you referring to little black spots as artifacts?  tri x and t-max films are different with  the latter being a t-grain film so that may account for the difference. It seems to me that the artifacts are t grains that did not dev like the others, ( developed more than the grains around them?)    Curious. What is the purpose/goal of developing B&W film in a reverse process?

Comment: @Determinant Your understanding of film dev is incomplete **"I thought it would be ok because before the second dev, the film should be fully exposed"**  I think you mean fully developed. The film is exposed to light in the camera and then developed in the tank.  You do not "fully develop" film you develop it to a certain point to achieve proper density based on how much light it was exposed to in camera. You then have to stop the development process at that certain point by using the stop bath. By opening  the tank you exposed the film to more light and then development continued.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to trouble shoot but my best guess -- the dichromate bleach was exhausted or contaminated.

Comment: I also suspect this. Do you mean it might be contaminated by the second developer? (I did wash for long after the first dev, so it does not seem likely to be contaminated by the first) Also, by "exhausted", do you mean I might not supply enough bleach?

Comment: I did notice greenish color in the problematic area during the second exposure (after bleaching and clearing). Does that mean the clearing is not enough and some parts were contaminated by dichromate?